# SQL Optimization Memory Issue

Tags: sql, optimization

I'm not the most experienced SQL writer, but here goes. I have a query which runs to display a list of items in a table CusHAWB. potentially be 2000 - 3000 records in this table. I have a seperate table JobPackLines which has another 2000-3000 records. I need to run through and check CUSHAWB and join to JobPacklines.
After that, I need to identify JobPackLine records which dont exist in JobPackLines.

The query runs fine before I add the UNION, but after that it keeps giving me low memory errors :(. I suppose I need help optimizing this query ?

this is my query:

```
Select 
CusMAWB.CM_MAWB AS Masterbill, 
CS_ConsignmentNum AS LineItem,
CS_HAWB AS HouseBill,
JL_RefNumber AS Number,
CASE CS_CustomsStatus 
    WHEN 'ACK' then 'Acknowledgement'
    WHEN 'IAR' Then 'Inspections/Audit Requirement'
    WHEN 'CLR' then 'ECI Accepted'
    WHEN 'CAN' then 'Cancelled'
    WHEN 'ERR' then 'ECI in Error'
    WHEN 'REF' then 'ECI Rejected'
    WHEN 'NSC' then 'Not sent to Customs'
    WHEN 'STC' then 'Sent to Customs'
    WHEN 'FEQ' then 'Formal Declaration Required'
    WHEN 'WOF' then 'Consignment Written Off'
    Else CS_CustomsStatus end  AS CustomsStatus,
    CASE    WHEN CS_CustomsStatus = 'WOF' AND JobPackLines.JL_RefNumber IS NOT NULL then 'Cleared'
    WHEN CS_CustomsStatus = 'WOF' AND JobPackLines.JL_RefNumber IS NULL then 'Missing' 
    WHEN CS_CustomsStatus  = 'FEQ' then 'Held' end AS OutturnStatus,
JobPackLines.JL_CustomAttrib2 AS SortLocation,
JobPackLines.JL_CustomAttrib4 AS ScanDate,
JobPackLines.JL_PackageCount AS Packs,
JobPackLines.JL_ActualWeight AS Weight,
JobPackLines.JL_Length AS Length,
JL_Width AS width,
JL_Height AS Height,
JL_ActualVolume AS Volume,
JL_CustomAttrib1 as TPID,
JL_CustomAttrib3 AS FreightFlowID,
JL_CustomFlag1 AS ManualSort,
'?' AS ManifestCheckBox,
CM_DepartureDate AS DepartureDate,
CASE WHEN JS_UniqueConsignRef IS NULL then 'No Shipment' WHEN JS_UniqueConsignRef =''then 'No Shipment' else JS_UniqueConsignref end AS Shipment,
CASE WHEN CS_CustomsStatus = 'WOF' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalClearedexpected,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_PK IS NOT NULL AND CS_CustomsStatus = 'WOF' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalClearedScanned,
CASE WHEN CS_CustomsStatus='FEQ' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalHeldExpected,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_PK IS NOT NULL AND CS_CustomsStatus='FEQ' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalHeldScanned,
CASE WHEN JL_PK IS NULL  then 1 else 0 end AS TotalMissingItems,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_PK IS NOT NULL AND JL_CustomFlag2='Y' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalNonManifested,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_CustomFlag1 ='Y' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalManualSort,
CM_MessageReference AS ECI

from CusMAWB 
LEFT JOIN CusHAWB on CS_CM=CM_PK AND CS_HAWB <> ''
LEFT JOIN Jobshipment on CS_JS=JS_PK
LEFT JOIN JobPackLines on JL_JS=JS_PK AND JL_RefNumber=CS_HAWB

Union

Select 
CusMAWB.CM_MAWB AS Masterbill, 
CS_ConsignmentNum AS LineItem,
'' AS HouseBill,
JL_RefNumber AS Number,
''  AS CustomsStatus,
'Missing' AS OutturnStatus,
JobPackLines.JL_CustomAttrib2 AS SortLocation,
JobPackLines.JL_CustomAttrib4 AS ScanDate,
JobPackLines.JL_PackageCount AS Packs,
JobPackLines.JL_ActualWeight AS Weight,
JobPackLines.JL_Length AS Length,
JL_Width AS width,
JL_Height AS Height,
JL_ActualVolume AS Volume,
JL_CustomAttrib1 as TPID,
JL_CustomAttrib3 AS FreightFlowID,
JL_CustomFlag1 AS ManualSort,
'?' AS ManifestCheckBox,
'' AS DepartureDate,
CASE WHEN JS_UniqueConsignRef IS NULL then 'No Shipment' WHEN JS_UniqueConsignRef =''then 'No Shipment' else JS_UniqueConsignref end AS Shipment,
0 AS TotalClearedexpected,
0 AS TotalClearedScanned,
0 AS TotalHeldExpected,
0 AS TotalHeldScanned,
1 AS TotalMissingItems,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_PK IS NOT NULL AND JL_CustomFlag2='Y' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalNonManifested,
CASE WHEN JobPackLines.JL_CustomFlag1 ='Y' then 1 else 0 end AS TotalManualSort,
CM_MessageReference AS ECI

from CusMAWB 
LEFT JOIN CusHAWB on CS_CM=CM_PK AND CS_HAWB <> ''
LEFT JOIN Jobshipment on CS_JS=JS_PK
LEFT JOIN JobPackLines on JL_JS=JS_PK AND JL_RefNumber<>CS_HAWB
```

Comment: I dont know where to start really. any help wold be apreciated

Comment: By using `UNION` you are filtering any duplicates in either left or right set, eg after `A UNION B` there will be no duplicate rows in the resulting set (even if such duplicates appear only in set A). Are you sure it is your intention to explicitely filter such duplicate rows? If not, you should be using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Hi TT. thanks for reply. I dont know to tell you the truth. What I'm trying to do is to show all records in CusHawb with a matchin line in JobPackLine, then I want to show all the items in JobPackLine which dont have a match in CusHAWB.